# Change jQuery animation when window resizes

Tags: jquery, resize, window

On my website I use the following code to animate a hover action:

```
jQuery('#portfolio .project').hover( function() {
   // Animate icon
   jQuery(this).find('.overlay').animate({opacity:1.0, top:'75px'}, 300);
}, function() {
   // Hide icon
   jQuery(this).find('.overlay').animate({opacity:0, top:'155px'}, 300);
});
```

so that when the user hovers over a project an icon will be displayed as an overlay.

In this situation the image is 940px wide. But the website will be responsive, so is it possible to make this code variable depending on the window size of the browser?
For example, when the browser width is 768px the icon will animate to 'top:100px' instead of 75px.

I've made a start with this, but have no idea how to go further.

```
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
   var window_width = jQuery(window).width();
```

Comment: Do you mean when the browser width is greater than, equal to, or less than 768px?

Comment: Yes, sort of media queries.
If width is smaller than 768 --> top:100px
If width is smaller than 320 --> top 30px, etc. If possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, the easiest way for you is CSS.

Since your page is responsive, you already have different CSS styles for different window sizes. If you add an additional class and toggle that, you can easily set different values.

For your CSS:

```
/*
 * if the device width is bigger or equal to 768,
 * set the hover top property to 100px
 */

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) {
    .overlay.hover {
        top: 100px;
    }
}

/*
 * if the device width is smaller or equal to 767
 * set the hover top property to 75px
 */

@media only screen and (max-device-width : 767px) {
    .overlay.hover {
        top: 75px;
    }
}
```

Then, all that remains is toggle class!

```
jQuery('.container').hover( function() {
    // Animate icon
    jQuery(this).find('.overlay').stop().toggleClass('hover', 300).animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 300);
}, function() {
    // Hide icon
    jQuery(this).find('.overlay').stop().toggleClass('hover', 300).animate({
        opacity: 0.2
    }, 300);
});​
```

However, if you think this is too much effort (though it's much prettier), you can always just do it in javascript too:

```
var animatetop = getAnimateTop();

jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    animatetop = getAnimateTop();
});

jQuery('#portfolio .project').hover( function() {
    // Animate icon
    jQuery(this).find('.overlay').stop().animate({
        opacity: 1.0,
        top: animatetop + 'px'
    }, 300);
}, function() {
    // Hide icon
    jQuery(this).find('.overlay').stop().animate({
        opacity: 0,
        top:'155px'
    }, 300);
});

function getAnimateTop() {
    if(jQuery(this).width() >= 768) {
        return 100;
    } else {
        return 75;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! Didn't know this was possible with CSS. But I would like to animate the icon. So it sort of "slides" into the image on hover. From the bottom to the center. In your code it's fading in. Is it also possible to animate the class?

Comment: I have edited the Javascript code! I think animations should work now. I used the wrong function ;)

Comment: I just figured out the css-javascript version contains some bugs. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VmeET/ The javascript version however works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/8qZeq/ I suggest to use the javascript version!